# Weblogic 12 ignore realm-name in weblogic-application.xml

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to use a custom realm into my webapp deployed in weblogic version 12.2.1.4.0 to manage login (through a form based authentication), but even if the new realm is correctly defined and also the SQLAuthenticator provider, when i try to set the realm name, according to [Oracle guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/app_xml.htm#WLPRG390), the results is that at deploy or starts of the application weblogic logs that the configuration is ignored:

> <Warning: Ignore the realm name: myrealm in
> deployment descriptor.>

This problems occurs even when i configure the name of the standard WL realm "myrealm".

The SQLAuthenticator provider (readonly) works good and if i configure it in the default realm the login works, but the users and groups specific of the application are mixed with the system users and can be inherited by others application eventually deployed on the same WL instance and I want to avoid this.

weblogic-application.xml is correctly contained in META-INF dir of the EAR that contain the WAR and this is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_6.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.8/weblogic-application.xsd">
    <wls:security>
        <wls:realm-name>myrealm</wls:realm-name>
    </wls:security>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Comment: you may let myrealm as the default realm and set your new realm in the weblogic-application.xml file

Comment: @Jay i removed realm.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin is what i tried to do, putting in realm-name the name of my realm, but is ignored as i wrote.

Comment: myrealm is the default realm. What is yours ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin probably there is a misunderstanding abount "my realm" with space :D i intend the realm i defined.
To be clear, the new realm is named "customRealm". I changed the name of the realm in weblogic-application.xml:
<wls:realm-name>customRealm</wls:realm-name>

But i obtain always the same warning by weblogic like the default realm "myrealm":

<Warning: Ignore the realm name: customRealm in deployment descriptor.>